# Error on 'npm run deploy': "Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout:"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, github, npm, github-pages

I keep getting this error when trying to deploy my react project with gh-pages.

My personal access token on GitHub recently expired and the error occurred after I renewed the token.

This is the error I'm getting:

```
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout:
    build/asset-manifest.json
    build/service-worker.js
Please commit your changes or stash them before you switch branches.
Aborting
```

Comment: Plz add package json to see  wht deploy is executing

Comment: especially the deploy script